Postgress Test Container Fails to Start
Git Repo: https://github.com/SMHosseinM/demo
I'm using Postgress testContainer to spin up a postgress container for my integration test. However, when running the test, the application context fails to load.
At the root of the stack trace, I'm getting database connection error. As I move up to in the stack trace, it also says that it cannot inject my beans annotated with @RestController, @Service, and @Repository.  I suspect that there might be a misconfiguration with Testcontainers, but I'm unsure where the issue lies.
This is a list of container related dependencies I have used in gradle:
testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers"
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.20.1'
testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.20.1"

This is my application-test.yaml property file:
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /myapp

This is the application where I'm setting up container initialisation:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Container
    protected static final PostgreSQLContainer postgresSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:alpine3.18")
        .withDatabaseName("mydb")
        .withUsername("admin")
        .withPassword("pass");

    static {
        postgresSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerPgProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url",
            () -> String.format("jdbc:postgresql://%s:%d/mydb", postgresSQLContainer.getHost(), postgresSQLContainer.getFirstMappedPort()));
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", () -> "admin");
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", () -> "pass");
    }

}

This is the stack trace I'm getting:
Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@31a024ea testClass = com.myapp.backendservice.app.service.guest.web.GuestControllerIntegrationTest, locations = [], classes = [com.myapp.backendservice.BackendServiceApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7d61eccf, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2427e004, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@641856, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2db2dd9d, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@37fbe4a8, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@2f3c6ac4, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@49382736, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@232b1619], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@31a024ea testClass = com.myapp.backendservice.app.service.guest.web.GuestControllerIntegrationTest, locations = [], classes = [com.myapp.backendservice.BackendServiceApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7d61eccf, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2427e004, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@641856, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2db2dd9d, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@37fbe4a8, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@2f3c6ac4, org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicPropertiesContextCustomizer@49382736, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@232b1619], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'guestService' defined in file [/Users/test/myapp/myappe/backend-service/build/classes/java/main/com/myapp/backendservice/app/service/guest/service/GuestService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'guestRepository' defined in com.myapp.backendservice.app.service.guest.repository.GuestRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on BackendServiceApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at app//org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'guestRepository' defined in com.myapp.backendservice.app.service.guest.repository.GuestRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on BackendServiceApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.mapping.JdbcMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1705)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1454)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcMappingContext' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcCustomConversions' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcCustomConversions]: Factory method 'jdbcCustomConversions' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcDialect' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1252)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcCustomConversions' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcCustomConversions]: Factory method 'jdbcCustomConversions' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcDialect' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcCustomConversions]: Factory method 'jdbcCustomConversions' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcDialect' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcDialect' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:486)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1261)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcCustomConversions(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:154)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jdbc.JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.jdbcCustomConversions(JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.java:127)
    at java.base@17.0.10/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146)

Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:267)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(SpringLiquibase.java:259)
    at app//liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:191)
    at app//liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:200)
    at app//liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:190)
    at app//liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
    at app//liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:257)
    at app//liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:250)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32897 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at app//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at app//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273)
    at app//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446)
    at app//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:144)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at app//liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(SpringLiquibase.java:254)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:554)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)
    ... 133 more


Is your database available yet? It mean you can login with terminal or another?

I am quite sure that your poblem come from Dependency. Have a look again the version, the library (.class file) you using

@NguyenHuuPhuc The dependencies look fine. The issue turns to be intermittent. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it fails due to application context issues.

@NguyenManhCuong the database is up and running

can you share a project on github that reproduces the issue?

@EddúMeléndez I created a project reproducing the issue and pasted the link above. https://github.com/SMHosseinM/demo

Add the following dependency runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

@Hossein, what is the dataSource config, you can provide template?
